# how to fetch cursor values into an object

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types, object-type

I want to fetch values from a cursor and store them in an object....
I tried doing the same with Record i got the output

```
DECLARE
CURSOR lc_emp_fetch 
IS 
  SELECT emp_no,emp_name FROM maniemp;
  TYPE r_emp_record IS RECORD (
                               eno maniemp.emp_no%TYPE,
                               ename maniemp.emp_name%TYPE
                              );
TYPE t_emp IS TABLE OF r_emp_record;
lt_emp_rcd t_emp;                            
BEGIN
  OPEN lc_emp_fetch;
  LOOP
  FETCH lc_emp_fetch BULK COLLECT INTO lt_emp_rcd LIMIT 5;
  EXIT WHEN lt_emp_rcd.COUNT=0;
    FOR indx IN 1..lt_emp_rcd.COUNT
    LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lt_emp_rcd(indx).eno||lt_emp_rcd(indx).ename);
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
CLOSE lc_emp_fetch;
END;
/
```

but when i try doing the same in an object its not working... i surfed all the websites but didn't get proper example program. This is my object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Typename3 AS OBJECT ( 
  eno number, 
  ename varchar2(500), 
  esal number);

SHOW ERRORS;
```

I am new to this i don't know how to do this can someone help me with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to try the above example with an object and type then you should create both are at schema level it means

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE type R_EMP_OBJECT as object(
                                   eno number,
                                   ename varchar2(30)
                                  );
```

and

```
 `create or replace type t_emp IS TABLE OF r_emp_object`;
```

then

```
DECLARE    
        lt_emp_rcd t_emp;                            
        BEGIN
          select r_emp_object (emp,ename) bulk collect into lt_emp_rcd 
     FROM emp;
            FOR indx IN 1..lt_emp_rcd.COUNT
            LOOP
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lt_emp_rcd(indx).eno||lt_emp_rcd(indx).ename);
            END LOOP;  
        END;
```

**Edit** I have tried with cursors, the below code is working fine

```
 DECLARE 
 CURSOR C1
 IS   
  SELECT emp_no,emp_name FROM maniemp;
 C2 C1%ROWTYPE;
 LT_EMP_RCD T_EMP;                            
 BEGIN
 OPEN C1;
 LOOP
 FETCH  C1 INTO C2 ;
 SELECT R_EMP_OBJECT(C2.EMP_NO,C2.EMP_NAME) BULK COLLECT INTO LT_EMP_RCD FROM DUAL;
 EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
 FOR INDX IN 1..LT_EMP_RCD.COUNT
 LOOP
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LT_EMP_RCD(INDX).ENO||' '||LT_EMP_RCD(INDX).ENAME);
 END LOOP;
 END LOOP; 
 CLOSE C1; 
 END;
```

Comment: hey tarun it works thanks.. now i wanna fetch value from the cursor. how am i supposed to do that .. i have declared the cursor in the above example..

Comment: yes tarun..this can be done without cursor  but i need to use cursor in my project.. starting from the basic

Comment: thanks dude.. this works perfectly and this is what i want ... is there any way to achieve the same thing without using implicit cursor

Comment: Yes @manikandan we have another way to do this go through the concepts of pl/sql collections and records surely you will find multiple ways .